# Стрелки в графе Git

Tags: git

Что означают стрелки в графе Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стрелки обозначают, что и куда мержится, они ставятся от родительского коммита к дочернему.
UPD: конкретно на гитхабе, насколько я понимаю, они ставятся в местах разделения и слияния веток, чтобы обозначить направление разделения / слияния